# Spring Security - overriding default configuration in profile

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

Context is Spring 3.1 (we use Spring MVC and Spring Security).

What we are trying to do is an admin page only available when the `admin` profile is active. With Spring Security, we tried something like:

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" entry-point-ref="entryPointDenied">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="denyAll" />
</security:http>

<beans profile="admin">
    <security:http use-expressions="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/admin/**" access="permitAll" />
        <sec:form-login/>
    </security:http>
</beans>
```

But that doesn't work as we can't override `security:http` definitions (we tried using the `http@name` attribute). So with above configuration, we get

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: A universal match pattern ('/**') is defined  before other patterns in the filter chain, causing them to be ignored.
```

Also we can't use the negated profile (i.e. `profile="!admin"`) feature as it is introduced in Spring 3.2.

Ideally the solution should be purely Spring configuration.

**Edit:** added missing use-expressions="true" to the second security:http

Comment: Can't you just introduce a 'nonadmin' profile and wrap the first <http> element in it?

Comment: This makes sense, but I would like to avoid creating 2 profiles to control the access to one feature. Spring profiles are a great feature but they can get quickly out of hand. We already have more than 10 of them after just 6 months, all with very different levels of concern. I'm afraid of what it will look like in a year. Anyway, all this to say I was hoping there is a way to not use the security namespace and wire simple beans which can then be overridden. Or even a solution not involving Spring Security.